# How to add CSV file names as Column Headers in a dataframe using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I'm trying to concatenate some specific columns from all the CSV files in a directory. I'm able to do all of that and make a resulting CSV file. The thing is since I don't know which columns belong to which CSV file I would like to make the header of each column as the CSV file it came from.

For eg.

```
CSVFile1: 
Col1|Col2

CSVFile2: 
Col1|Col2

CSVMergeFile:
CSVFile1|CSVFile2|CSVFile1|CSVFile2
Col1    |Col1    |Col2    |Col2
```

The following is the code I'm using to concatenate the columns:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
p = input("Enter folder path :")
n = int(input("Enter number of columns: "))
col = []
for i in range(0, n):
    ele = int(input())
    col.append(ele)
path = f'{p}'
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
li = []    
for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, usecols=col, index_col=False, header=0)
    li.append(df)    
frame = pd.concat(li, axis=1, ignore_index='False')
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: The structure you want isn't clear to me. Do you want a multi-index? Is "Col1" in your desired results another column name, or a value? Do you want multiple columns with the same name: that is, more than one column named "CsvFile1"?

Comment: So say I'm picking Col1 from CSVFile1 and also Col1 from CSVFile2 and merging them in a new CSV file. I just want their Column header saying CSVFile1 and CSVFile2,i.e, which files were the columns picked from.
Does it help?

Comment: So then you'd have two columns named CSVFile1 if there are two columns in that file?

Comment: Yea it will have 2 same column names

Comment: I would recommend not doing that. Consider naming them something like CSVFile1-col1, CSVFile1-col2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create `key` which is the csv filename and concat it within a dict comprehension. This will create an index with the filename.

```
from pathlib import Path 
import pandas as pd 


p = input("Enter folder path :")
#change .stem to .name if you want the `.csv` appendage.
dfs = {file.stem : pd.read_csv(file, usecols=col, header=0)
                               ) for file in Path(p).glob('*.csv')}

df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

---

`dfs` will be a dictionary of file names with with the key being a dataframe.